# MySQL update query using WHERE and HAVING must have always multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, having

I want to update the price of brand 44 products
except ID's 17466 and 17467
considering only records from category 20 or category 22

```
UPDATE products_test
SET price=ROUND(price*1.06,0)
WHERE brand = 44 AND id NOT IN ('17466', '17467')
HAVING category = '20' OR category = '22'
```

I get an error on the HAVING line in the next query.

If I use SELECT the query runs ok.
I must use multiple tables or can go one table?
Probably I miss some operator or brackets
Im not an expert in MySQL

Comment: Having is used with group by in a select; seems like you just want to add `and (category = '20' OR category = '22')` to your where

Answer (score 0):

If the `category` is a column from `products_test`, you can add the condition to the `WHERE`-clause.

```
UPDATE products_test
SET price=ROUND(price*1.06,0)
WHERE brand = 44 AND id NOT IN ('17466', '17467') and category in ('20', '22')
```